# Торговля зерном или зерна?

Tags: стилистика, склонение

Встретил в тексте фразу: *промышленник занимался торговлей зерна.* Правилен ли тут родительный падеж — *зернА*?  Я бы сказал: *занимался торговлей зерном.*

Отвечаю на вопрос: Текст абсолютно современный. Девушка в Инстаграме ведёт архитектурно-исторический блог про московские исторические здания. И рассказывает про одно из них. Где жил известный чаеторговец Высоцкий. Кто из архитекторов его построил. И даёт краткие исторические справки о владельце и пишет, что изначально он занимался торговлей зерна, а потом переключился на чай... Так что определенно он продавец, а не покупатель.))))

Comment: А по стилистике вообще бы нужно было написать: "... промышленник занимался ещё и продажей зерна...". Либо: "...торговал зерном...". Так бы автор избежал "скользкого" места.

Comment: @behemothus, это вам в личку Олег написал (то, что вы добавили), что ли?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой почти.))) Личку я бы не стал обнародовать, а написано это было путем редактирования моего ответа. Но там совсем этому тексту не место.

Comment: Понятно))) Ну да, конечно не место)

Answer (score 2):

Интересный вопрос. Все зависит от контекста... Что именно делал тот промышленник? Покупал или продавал? И еще от того, какого времени текст. И к какому времени относится.

Выражение **"Торговля зерна"** в принципе возможно, но в необычном значении. Оно означает, что кто-то **покупает** зерно на торгах. Сейчас такое значение вышло из широкого употребления, но еще не окончательно потерялось в "лингвистической памяти" носителей.

Тут вот какое дело. Прежде всего о зависимых словах при существительных, означающих действия по глаголу. Глаголы переходные, то есть позволяющие иметь при себе прямое дополнение (винительный падеж без предлога) обычно порождают существительные, требующие родительного падежа. *Мыть машину - мытье машины. Издавать книгу - издание книги. Производить товар - производство товара.* То есть выражение **"торговля зерна"** было бы мотивировано конструкцией **"торговать зерно"***.

Сейчас, конечно, такой винительный падеж при глаголе "торговать" не характерен. Но если текст относится к народному творчеству или событиям не позднее XVIII века, то там могут встречаться обороты с прямым дополнением при глаголе "торговать".

> Купец тогда сказал: «Подлинно, что это диво-дивное, чудо-чудное», — а потом 
>   начал того гуся торговать и, сторговав его за дорогие
>   деньги, взял на свой корабль и скоро после того отправился в свое
>   отечество. [Диво-дивное, чудо-чудное, сказка русская (1788)]

~

> Наконецъ, посидѣвши у меня и напившись кофею, наѣвшись сластей и овощей, всѣ 
>   боярыни, а съ ними нѣкоторые и изъ мущинъ, поѣхали на
>   ярмонку, отчасти глазѣть на толпы взадъ и впередъ ходящаго народа и на
>   множество каретъ и колясокъ, туда и сюда разъѣзжающихъ между онымъ,
>   отчасти ходить по лавкамъ, пересматривать и торговать товары. [А. Т.
>   Болотов. [Съѣздъ дворянъ на ярмарку] (1789-1816)]

~

> — «Что, цел, говорит, поросенок, которого я торговал?» [Н. В. Успенский. 
>   Поросенок (1858)]

(Примеры из нацкорпуса).

Но тут вот что интересно. "Торговать (товары)", как легко видеть из примеров, означает не продавать их, а покупать, точнее "торговаться, сбивая цену".

> **Торговать** ...
>   2. [устар., прост. собираясь купить что-л., прицениваться, сговариваться о цене] 
>   что. Я... видела одну женщину, которая торговала
>   кусок материи (Остр.).

(Д. Э. Розенталь. Управление в русском языке)
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x

Другими словами, на торгах ***продавец торгует "чем", а покупатель - торгует "что".*** "Вариант покупателя" и порождает ***торговля "чего"***.
Решайте сами, возможно ли подобное значение в вашем тексте.

//=====

> Текст абсолютно современный. Девушка в Инстаграме ведёт
>   архитектурно-исторический блог про московские исторические здания. И
>   рассказывает про одно из них. Где жил известный чаеторговец Высоцкий.
>   Кто из архитекторов его построил. И даёт краткие исторические справки
>   о владельце и пишет, что изначально он занимался торговлей зерна, а
>   потом переключился на чай... Так что определенно он продавец, а не
>   покупатель.))))

Тогда остается принять, что девушка ошиблась. Или просто спутав с глаголом "продавать" и отглагольным существительным "продажа" ("занялся продажей зерна"") или как следствие неудачной стилизации "под историю".

Answer (score 1):

Так сказать нельзя, поскольку **торговать** - *непереходный* (вне жаргонного употребления вроде "доллар сегодня торгуется так-то") глагол, от которого (вместе с его дополнением - "торговать зерн**ом**") и образовано словосочетание с отглагольным существительным: **торговля зерном**. Если автор хотел избежать "повторного" творительного падежа, можно было написать *занимался продажей зерна*.

Comment: А вот герой Льва Николаича иного мнения. )))) ― *Оченно скупы Константин Дмитрич...,  окончательно ничего не укупишь. **Торговал пшеницу**, хорошие деньги давал*. ―  [Л. Н. Толстой. Анна Каренина (1878)]

Comment: Так то ведь купец говорит, нынешние биржевые и доллар "торгуют". Насчет покупателя согласен, он торгуется и выторговывает товар по сходной цене. А у нас торгуют, "размахивая" предлагаемым товаром.

Comment: Да хоть кто. Это значение признается устаревшим (а не просто просторечным) минимум двумя источниками (это навскидку - Розенталем и Кузнецовым).

Comment: (+) "Торговать" и "торговаться" - достаточно разные по смыслу глаголы, а не просто пара, отличающаяся возвратной формой. Сводить одно к другому и выводить одно из другого просто нельзя.